# typecast react typescript component class props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Starting with `React`, `Nextjs` with typescript

I have the following class which gives an error while accessing `avatar` and `name`

```
Property does not exists on type readonly
```

[image]

How can I typecast the properties properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.Component` is a generic class. You can specify the props there:

```
interface AvatarProps {
  avatar?: string;
  name: string;
}

class Avatar extends React.Component<AvatarProps> {
```

If you leave it out, the default is to assume there are no props.

Comment: Is there a way to do this while deconstructing the props? It doesn't seem like `React.Component<{ x, y }: CustomProps>` works like it does with functional components